# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat

I'm trying to insert data in my database, but I'm getting following error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WebContent/WEB-INF/dbinsertdata.jsp at line 14
```

here's my code.

dbinsertdata.jsp

```
11:    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbdemo";
12:    Connection connection = null;
13:    PreparedStatement pstatement = null;
14:    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
15:    int updateQuery = 0;
16:    if (name!=null && email!=null && username!=null && pass!=null){
```

I've already

- place the `com.mysql.jdbc.jar` in WEB-INF/lib.
- added the jar file in eclipse.
- set the classpath for mysql.

But I'm still getting the same error. what have I missed or doing wrong?

Comment: Enclose your database connection in try and catch block and run the program. If you still face the same issue, provide the stackTrace.

Comment: I hope you have not written the database connection code in your jsp. Please provide file names when you provide code.

Comment: @DhavalSimaria before, mysql was running, I can access my database without getting any error. But when I created a new project and add some java files, but same jsp files/source codes to my previous project, now I'm getting this error.

Comment: *from my previous

Comment: What I meant to ask is that the code that you have provided is in **dbinsertdata.jsp** file? If not then also provide the code from your jsp file since it is showing issue at line 14 of jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this jar is correct？
if not try this jar http://central.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar

Comment: I'm sure. Because I once used it in my previous project. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I tried the jar file you've given. but I'm still getting the same error